# Win32-SerialPort installation error

Tags: perl

When tried to install Win32-SerialPort in windows command prompt getting the following error, using activeperl 5.24.1 build(2402)64 bit, could anyone tell were it went wrong and the ways to insatll win32::SerialPort, I have both strawberry and active perl installed

```
cmd> perl -MCPAN -e shell

cpan>  install Win32::SerialPort
Database was generated on Thu, 09 Mar 2017 12:01:53 GMT

Running install for module 'Win32::SerialPort'
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/B/BB/BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/B/BB/BBIRTH/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\B\BB\BBIRTH\Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring B/BB/BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL line 35.
Device COM1 does not appear to exist. Testing impossible
No 'Makefile' created  BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Stopping: 'install' failed for 'Win32::SerialPort'.
Failed during this command:
 BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz          : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

**EDIT:**

After suggestion from Jens I have set the path to `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32`

Thanks for the suggestion "cmd.exe" error vanished but
shows up with the following error now, any solutions?

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/test1.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 309 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  157
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/test2.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 146 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  27
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/test3.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 264 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  149
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/test4.t (Wstat: 256 Tests: 518 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  366
  Non-zero exit status: 1
t/test7.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 90 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  21-22
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=7, Tests=1808,  6 wallclock secs ( 0.27 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.31 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 5/7 test programs. 6/1808 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz
```

Also I am using both Activeperl and strwaberry perl will that be a problem?

Comment: Looks like there is the path to cmd missing in yout PATH variable: `Can't spawn "cmd.exe": No such file or directory at Makefile.PL `

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this?

Comment: try to execute `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\windows\system32` before you call `perl -MCPAN -e shell`

Comment: The issue is resolved but `Failed 5/7 test programs. 6/1808 subtests failed.
dmake.exe:  Error code 130, while making 'test_dynamic'
  BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe test -- NOT OK` getting the above error

Comment: If you look more carefully you will see that it failed six tests out of 1,327 in seven test *programs*. Checking the *capantesters* results as it suggests shows that it hasn't passed on a relevant platform (Windows) since version 5.20.1. I would be inclined to force the installation and bear in mind that there may be minor issues with the module.

Comment: "*I am using both Activeperl and strwaberry perl will that be a problem?*" ... Yes ... Because `perl2bat` does NOT specify full path to `perl`, you have to come up with a way to keep the two installations separate. It is doable (I have umpteen Perl installs, and one I use for day-to-day stuff), but you have to know more about working on the command line than you do.

Comment: Also, working with the serial port on Windows is not that hard. If your needs are simple (as [mine were](https://www.nu42.com/2015/08/playing-with-true-rng-hardware-random-number-generator.html)).

Answer (score 0):

**Strawberry Perl Version > 5.32:**

This problem should be resolved on Strawberry Perl `5.32`, `Win32::SerialPort` module will be installed by default.

---

**Strawberry Perl Version < 5.32:**

Here is a solution if you need to install `Win32::SerialPort` module but the Strawberry Perl < `5.32`:

1. Download the module tar ball:

> http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/B/BB/BBIRTH/Win32-SerialPort-0.22.tar.gz

2. unzip and you will get this folder:
   [image]
3. Modified the `Makefile.PL` to comment out all "COM1" section:
   [image]
4. using cmd:

> ```
> cd Win32-SerialPort-0.22
> perl Makefile.PL
> dmake
> dmake install
> ```

6. Enjoy it!!